# What does string.split do?

Tags: javascript

i know what string.split() does but im trying to understand someones React app, and i came across this:

```
newStr = newStr.split ? newStr.split(' ').reverse().join(' ') : newStr;
```

Comment: Did you try it? Type `'foo bar'.split(' ').reverse().join(' ')` into the console. If you know what `.split` does then what exactly is confusing you?

Comment: This is a common trick question asked in interviews lol

Comment: Hint: it's doing `str.split` not `str.split()`

Comment: It looks like it's supposed to split the string if it contains spaces

Comment: So if you know what `split` does, what part of the statement do you not understand?

Comment: i know what it does, i just didnt know what newStr.split did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In that context, `newStr.split` is testing to see whether `newStr` has a `.split` property - if it does, it assumes it is a method and calls `.split(' ').reverse().join(' ')` (reversing the order of words), otherwise it returns `newStr` unaltered.

That code will result in an error if `newStr` is `null` or `undefined`, or if it is some object with a `.split` property that is not a function that returns an array.

(As mentioned by Bergi) it would make more sense to test the type of `newStr` directly:

```
newStr = typeof newStr === "string" ? newStr.split(' ').reverse().join(' ') : newStr;

// OR
if (typeof newStr === "string") newStr = newStr.split(' ').reverse().join(' ');
```

Comment: …which is a bit weird, `if (typeof newStr == "string")) newStr = newStr.split().…;` would've been more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

It reverses the words of the input "sentence" string. If the input doesn't have `split` method or doesn't have any spaces it returns the original input.

Comment: Calling it a "sentence" sounds like the snippet would care about punctuation, which it doesn't :-)